# RabbitMQ error java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I tried to build a simple consumer application with rabbitmq. My rabbit configured with rabbit:3-management image on port 15672, so, in theory, there is no problem at least in application properties.

**Controller**

```
package com.example.consumer;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
public class ConsumerController {
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ConsumerController(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate){
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @PostMapping("consumer")
    public boolean addNote(@RequestBody Note note){
        note.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        System.out.println(note.getNote());
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitConfig.EXCHANGE, RabbitConfig.ROUTING_KEY, note);
        return note != null ? true : false;
    }
}
```

**RabbitMQ configuration**

```
package com.example.consumer;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {
    public static final String QUEUE="cons-queue";
    public static final String EXCHANGE="exch-cons";
    public static final String ROUTING_KEY="exch-cons-key";

    @Bean
    public Queue queue(){
        return new Queue(QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange topicExchange(){
        return new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange topicExchange){
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(queue)
                .to(topicExchange)
                .with(ROUTING_KEY);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

**application properties**

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=15672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest

server.port=3033
```

**Error**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException] with root cause

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:502) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:326) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1222) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1170) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:640) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:615) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:565) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:724) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:252) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2163) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2136) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1063) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1128) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1121) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at com.example.consumer.ConsumerController.addNote(ConsumerController.java:24) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
```

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Default Port is: **5672**.
It's defined in the RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT variable.

Source: [https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#define-environment-variables](http://Default:%205672,%20the%20manual%20has%20the%20answer.%20It%27s%20defined%20in%20the%20RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT%20variable.%20%20https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#define-environment-variables)

Port **15672**: It is used to access the management console of Rabbit MQ.

Change Port in property file from 15672 to 5672 and it will work!

Comment: thank you, it helped me a lot! But now I have a new error: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

Comment: also writes that there is an error in line 24 in the controller - rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitConfig.EXCHANGE, RabbitConfig.ROUTING_KEY, note);

Comment: @aron Instead of using RabbitTemplate  in controller , use this `@Autowired AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate`

Comment: changed it, but I still have a problem in the same controller line :'(

Comment: @aron Did you download and install/run RabbitMQ? It is not like ActiveMQ - it can't run embedded in a java application. check if you can access managment console on http://localhost:15672

Comment: Yes I have it, I have a docker container with rabbitmq manager

Comment: sorry, may I contact you somewhere? I can send screenshots, I would be very grateful!

Comment: hi, @aron sorry, but I don't have much expertise with the docker, you can post another question with new stack trace, the community would be able to help you! But In my opinion, I still doubt that the Rabbit MQ server is running inside docker, find a way to log/echo the status of rabbit-mq server whether its its running or not

Comment: Hello @LearningDeveloper, you was right! I had a problem with my rabbitmq manager!